# Jira search_issues error returns "project not identified"

Tags: python, jira, jira-plugin, python-jira

Trying to extract the data using Jira search issues but it's not identifying the project. Tried to check if it was an authentication error but it seems to be working fine. It always gives back the same error saying "XYZ not identified as project".

```py
from jira import JIRA 


jira_server = "https://preqin.atlassian.net" # jira server link
api_token = "" # jira api token 
account_id = "" # jira account id 

# authentication options 
options = {
           'server': jira_server, 
           'check_update': False, 
           'verify': True, 
           'get_server_info': False, 
           'oauth': { 
               'access_token': api_token, 
               'access_token_secret': account_id, 
             }
          } 

jira = JIRA(options) # connect to Jira
issues = jira.search_issues('project = "projectABC"') # retrieve issues 

print(issues) # print issue details for issues in issues
```

I've checked the project name and everything but I'm not able to rectify it.

Tried giving the shortcut for the project, the full name, with and without brackets and everything but couldn't fix it.

Comment: Please edit your code with proper formatting. There is a code block button in editor, which can be used for that. Your code is unreadable now

Comment: Hey @sudden_appearance, I've edited it can you please check now??

Comment: You didn't really fixed formatting

Comment: I would say recheck your API token. i'm not familiar with python, but also check that token is not required to be encrypted base64. check your request over POSTMAN.

Comment: Is the error actually "XYZ not identified as project" or are you just paraphrasing?